# Can I uninstall a chef cookbook I installed with `knife cookbook site install`?

Tags: chef, knife

I have installed a chef cookbook with `knife cookbook site install`. But I don't want/need that one. Is it possible to *uninstall* a cookbook like this? To clean up my `cookbooks` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove, use @TejayCardon answer above ^^

```
rm <cookbook_directory>/<cookbook name>
```

To remove Git branch, do

```
git branch -d CHEF-vendor-XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

```
rm <cookbook_directory>/<cookbook name>
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Doesn't that still leave the git branch with the `chef-vendor-XXX`?

Comment: not sure, I don't have a git repo for my chef repo.  I would assume you can just commit the change.